# How to debug "401 unauthorized error trying to authenticate" in Reddit OAuth

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, reddit

I'm confused on Reddit OAuth using Django framework. Do I need to use "REDDIT_APP_KEY" and "REDDIT_API_SECRET" as defined [in the docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/reddit.html), or is this code functional using "SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_KEY" and "SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_SECRET"?

I'm getting a `401 unauthorized error trying to authenticate`, even after making sure my keys are fine via curl.

```
enter codeif 'SSL_ONLY' in os.environ and os.environ['SSL_ONLY'] == "1":
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# ticketer specific configs
if 'REDDIT_APP_ID' not in os.environ or 'REDDIT_APP_ID' not in os.environ:
    raise Exception("You need to set social keys in your env. Either do it on the command line\
        \nor set it in .env and use `heroku local:run !!` to run this")
REDDIT_USERAGENT = ""
REDDIT_OAUTH_SCOPES = {"identity", "privatemessages"}
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_KEY = os.environ['SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_KEY']
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_SECRET = os.environ['SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_SECRET']
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {"duration": "permanent", "scope": ",".join(REDDIT_OAUTH_SCOPES)}
SOCIAL_AUTH_REDDIT_REDIRECT = "https://reddit-modmail-ticketer.herokuapp.com/complete/reddit/"
 here
```